# Upload static set of files in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to Azure DevOps, and I am trying to create my first pipeline to build a C++ project.
The VSBuild task is starting but expectedly it is lacking additional header and library files of various third-party libraries we are using.

The question is how to upload these files before VSBuild starts? I have not found a suitable solution.

1. Third-party libraries are not changing frequently, so we do not keep them under source control. Some of them are downloaded already as binaries.
2. Most of the advices suggest creating an artifact feed, but I failed to supply a static set of files to it.
3. There was a suggestion to create NuGet package for each library and create own NuGet server, but this sounds like an overkill for this task.
4. Of course I can upload files to a public location, then download it using a PowerShell script, but this does not sound right, because I would like to keep everything inside devops.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply commit them to your git repo and be done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, especially if they rarely change, I'd commit even the binaries to source control and be done with it.

But you can also create a universal package.

1. Put all the files you need in a folder structure you can publish as a package
2. run `az login` or `az devops login` to sign into your azure devops instance from the commandline
3. run `az artifacts universal publish` to publish the package to the feed.

Example for my own instance:

```
az artifacts universal publish
    --organization https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing/
    --project="demo-project"
    --scope project
    --feed headerfiles
    --name headerfiles
    --version 0.0.1
    --description "Packaging header files for project"
    --path c:\path\to\where\files\where\stored
```

Then update your azure pipeline to download the header files:

```yaml
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  inputs:
    command: 'download'
    downloadDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/headers/'
    feedsToUse: 'internal'
    vstsFeed: 'demo-project/headerfiles'
    vstsFeedPackage: 'headerfiles'
    vstsPackageVersion: '*'
```

Each time the headers change, download them all, add the changed headers in the  folder structure and publish them again with a higher version number. The task in the pipeline will always grab the latest version (`vstsPackageVersion: '*'`), though you can configure it to fetch a specific version as well (`vstsPackageVersion: '1.0.*'`).

Comment: jessehouwing, thank you, I finally put all libraries into separate repo, and used multi-repo build. Everything works fine. I have also tried a universal package, but ran into authentication problem of 'az', which I have not resolved yet.